# The set of all regular points of a self-adjoint operator in a Hilbert space is an open set.

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

I try to find a short method to prove that the set of all regular points $\rho(A)$ of a self-adjoint operator $A\in$ $\mathscr{B}(H)$ is an open set. Though it is true in any linear bounded operator in Hilbert space $H$ by routine check of openness, here more specific condition of " Self-Adjoint" is given.

The definitions are as follows:

A number $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ is called regular point iff $A-\lambda$$I$ is invertible, where $A\in$ $\mathscr{B}(X)$, $X$ is Banach space and $\overline{D(A)}$ = $X$.

Set of all regular points of $A$ is resolvent set of $A$ denoted by $\rho(A)$.

Comment: If you know a proof for any bounded linear operator, the same proof should work for a self-adjoint bounded linear operator since the set of self-adjoint bounded linear operators is a subset of the set of bounded linear operators.